What's an "Extrajudicial Penal Process" given for Viganò? Does that mean he is sentenced guilty without a trial?
On 5 July 2024, the Dicastery for the Doctrine of the Faith (DDF), in an "Extrajudicial Penal Process", simply declared Viganò as having incurred a latæ sententiæ excommunication, but was he even given a trial? Or does an "Extrajudicial Penal Process" mean he is sentenced as guilty without a trial?

Ab.Vigano the one who painted a bad image of Cdl.McCarrick is now judged as guilty of schism.
I wonder if all the people who believed in his accusations still trust this bishop.

@jongricafort Abp. Viganò's evidence speaks for itself. Also, the DDF has been headed by Victor Manuel Fernández since Sept. 2023, ghostwriter of Amoris Lætitia (whose dubia still have not been answered) and author of the scandalous Heal Me with your Mouth: The Art of Kissing.

No, a trial was scheduled for him.
The DDF summoned Abp. Viganò to an "extrajudicial penal trial" for 20 June 2024 in accordance with art. 1 §2 of SST [Sacramentorum sanctitatis tutela] and 1983 Code canon 1364:

Canonist Cathy Caridi claims that what Abp. Viganò called an "extrajudicial process" is really a synonym for "administrative process" (procedura administrativa) of 1983 Code:

Can. 1341— The Ordinary must start a judicial or an administrative procedure for the imposition or the declaration of penalties when he perceives that neither by the methods of pastoral care, especially fraternal correction, nor by a warning or correction, can justice be sufficiently restored, the offender reformed, and the scandal repaired.

Abp. Viganò described the process in his June 20, 2024, letter:

The Dicastery for the Doctrine of the Faith has informed me, with a simple email, of the initiation of an extrajudicial penal trial against me, with the accusation of having committed the crime of schism and charging me of having denied the legitimacy of “Pope Francis” of having broken communion “with Him” and of having rejected the Second Vatican Council. I have been summoned to the Palace of the Holy Office on June 20, in person or represented by a canon lawyer. I assume that the sentence has already been prepared, given that it is an extrajudicial process.

